# How to Licensing RemoteApp in Azure

Tags: azure, licensing, remoteapp

We need to use our ERP as SAAS (Software As A Service).  We tried the Azure trial for three months, and technically was a succes.  But, when we use RemoteApp services, the system asked for licenses (after 90 days), but We don't know if it is possible to paying monthly or how to obtain the licenses.

We have the great business opportunity, but I tried to contact microsfot support in Guatemala (Central America), and they always offered responses in 48 hrs. but after a month I haven't received any response.  My no. ticket is 130109017590.

Can anyone help me with my explain how licensing works in Azure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about licensing in Azure. If you are talking about something else please let me know.

Azure is set up as a [Pay as You Go](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) model where your initial monthly bill is $0 and it goes up from there based on how many resources you use.  Resources in this case can be computing hours (i.e. you have a package deployed to a Cloud Service via Web or Worker Role)

Most of the functionality in Azure falls under the Platform as a Service, where the details of networking, hardware, OS, etc. are handled for you and you just focus on building and deploying applications.  That being said, all of the licensing that you might normally have to worry about on an on-premise implementation is taken care of in Azure.

That just leaves billing.  Billing in Azure is pretty straightforward.  Smaller accounts (those that don't have an EA) are just set up with a credit card when you create the account.  You will be billed on a given interval (monthly) for all of the resources you used in the previous month.